# support 'symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64' error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app have errors about supporting 64 bit.

I was change some settings from main project and library(inner project).

1. Architectures -> Standard architectures(armv7, arm64)
2. Valid Architectures -> add 'arm64'
3. iOS Deployment Target -> iOS 7.0

But xcode printed this text.

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_inv", referenced from:
      -[abc pointTo:] in aLibrary.a(abc.o)
   .
   .
   .
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I need help about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced that issue.But in my case it got solved when i have added arm64 at first place in Valid architectures sequence.

e.g Valid Architectures:arm64 armv7s armv7.

I hope this will help you.